# Link in OneNote: from Desktop version to App version

Tags: onenote

Is it possible to create a shortcut in OneNote Desktop to open a Note in "OneNote for Windows 10" App?
By inserting the usual shortcut it opens the Block in the Desktop version, but I would like to avoid this.
Alternatively I can open it on the web, but I can't set the link to open in "OneNote for Windows 10".
Thanks in advance.